# React progressive web app add to home screen not working when uninstall

Tags: reactjs

Add home to screen only works when first launch in google chrome after that if i uninstall the app Add Home To Screen pop not reappear ! It only works if i clear history and cache.

```
{
  "short_name": "some text",
  "name": "Some text",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#fff",
  "background_color": "#fff"
}
```